# template to accommodate pointer-to and non-pointer

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a trick to make a template function that returns an object *either in the stack or in the heap?*

```
template <class Type>
Type ReturnAbstract(int a) {
  return Type(a);
}

template <class Type>
Type* ReturnAbstract(int a) {
  return new Type(a);
}
```

So, is there a trick to support both return types with a single template?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Slava In some cases I am using the same code to produce an object which, half of the times has to be returned as a local stack object, and the other half as a heap object (shared_pointer to be exact). I was thinking that maybe I can abstract that in a single template rather than have multiple implementations...

Comment: Can you use C++17?

Comment: Let's assume I can use C++17, if that's essential.

Comment: How do you decide what to return?

Comment: The method caller decides which version to use, according to his specific needs. Half callers require one, the other half require the other version.

Comment: @BillKotsias what's wrong with always returning by value and letting the caller move it into a smart pointer by themselves?

Comment: @Quentin Because they need to make an additional copy to move from stack to heap

Comment: @BillKotsias Probably not. If the function looks like your example, that will almost certainly RVO (guaranteed for c++17) and then it can move that rvalue into the `std::shared_pointer`.

Comment: What's wrong with calling `std::make_shared` or not directly? I don't see the sense in this kind of function without any more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`constexpr if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) in conjunction with a placeholder return type, we can have the caller control stack or heap

```
template <class Type, bool OnHeap=false>
auto ReturnAbstract(int a) {
  if constexpr (OnHeap)
    return new Type(a);
  else
    return Type(a);
}
```

usage:

```
int main(){
    auto on_stack = ReturnAbstract<int, false>(1);
    auto on_heap = ReturnAbstract<int, true>(2);

    std::cout << on_stack << std::endl;
    std::cout << *on_heap << std::endl;
    delete on_heap;
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ANWv7wKJuZg3dGQE)

---

Edit: As Quentin pointed out, raw pointers like this are not a good idea on modern C++.

You could instead use a [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to still allocate on the heap, but in a safe way:

```
template <class Type, bool OnHeap=false>
auto ReturnAbstract(int a) {
  if constexpr (OnHeap)
    return std::make_unique<Type>(a);
  else
    return Type(a);
}
```

### [Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OPqXVAhRGDnsxUxA)

Comment: @Quentin: This is just what OP wants. I suppose I should advocate for smart pointers.

Comment: @AndyG Never saw `auto` as return method type. Is this C++17 only?

Comment: @BillKotsias: It was introduced in C++11, with some limitations, and then expanded on in C++14

Comment: @AndyG C++11 didn't have return type deduction, `auto` was for trailing return types. Thanks for the smart pointer ;)

Comment: @Quentin: Trailing return types can be used for return type deduction :-) Edit: I see the distinction you're making, though. In this kind of return type deduction, the compiler infers it from your return statements. In trailing return type deduction (C++11), it was inferred from the trailing expression (which could use `decltype()` and other metaprogramming, but it wasn't inferred from your return statement)

Comment: @AndyG well that's not deduction if you have to spell it out, but I get what you mean.

Comment: @Quentin: You're right. Thanks for going easy on me about it.

Comment: This interface is terrible. A boolean to decide between pointer and value returns?

Comment: @rubenvb do you have a better design?

Comment: @rubenvb: I'm confused about your comment. This is exactly what OP wanted; the caller would specify if they wanted to return on the stack or the heap, and OP wanted it to go through a single template function. I think interface design is more or less moot, right? If OP wanted to use two functions with descriptive names like `allocate_on_heap` and `allocate_on_stack`, they would have.

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne The better interface would depend on what this code is supposed to do. Currently, it just obscures away the real operations behind a template argument, which seems daft without extra context. This question smells like an XY problem to me.